# False extra page numbers in the glossary

Tags: glossaries

I do not understand why I am getting an extra page number "2" in the glossary below. The term appears only on Page 1 but not on Page 2. How can I get rid of this false reference?

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{t}{name={term},
description={description of the term}}

The \gls{t} appears on this page.

\newpage

No glossary words on this page.

\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I compiled the code with  pdflatex + makeglossaries + pdflatex
The output looks like this

Page 1:

[image: Page 1 contains the term]

Page 2:

[image: Page 2 contains no terms]

Page 3: ( Note the false reference to Page 2 )

[image: The glossary has an extra link to Page 2]

Also note that the `indexonlyfirst` option of the `glossaries` package is neither relevant to this problem nor solves it.

Comment: Welcome! Define your glossary entries before `\begin{document}`. Also, `\glsaddall` adds all glossary entries. Hence, those entries are added on that page, despite the claim there asserting otherwise.

Comment: @cfr Thanks. After leaving out `\glsaddall`, the extra page references disappeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\glsaddall
```

Adds also the occurrence in the glossary itselfs
One possible change could be

```
\glsaddallunused
```